# resolver formula con variable obtenida desde base de datos PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema que no consigo resolver.
En una base de datos **MySQL** tengo almacenadas unas formulas que contienen variables escritas (Ejem: `ceiling($variable/53,1000)`).
Teniendo una variable con el mismo nombre ya definida anteriormente, como puedo hacer en **PHP** para obtener el resultado de dicha formula?
No sé si me explico.
Gracias

Comment: Parece cosa de utilizar `eval` pero no es muy recomendable su uso... Revisa la documentación de esta función, sobretodo por el tema de las condiciones que debe tener el código.

Comment: Podrías lograrlo con [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php), aunque te advierto de entrada que su uso podría ser muy peligroso (lee la documentación). Habría sido mejor que guardes `$variable` en la base de datos y no todo la fórmula. Así, usarías `ceiling()` en el contexto que le corresponde, que es PHP. Lo que estás haciendo al guardar funciones en una base de datos es tirar a la BD algo que corresponde a PHP, con el consiguiente esfuerzo y riesgo que supone llevarlo ahora a su contexto.

Comment: He intentado con `eval()` pero no me funciona. La formula con `ceiling()` la he puesto como ejemplo, cada una de los registros de la base de datos tiene una formula diferente y por eso he puesto en la base de datos las formulan en vez de en el PHP.